# Star rating no meu simple-form do Rails nao envia o valor

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Estou utilizando um plugin JQuery para estilizar um input field meu com o estilo de "star rating", sendo que essa é a biblioteca: http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating.

Eu chamo o atributo no slim da seguinte maneira:

```
td = f.input :score, label: false, input_html: {class: 'rating'}
```

E então o visual dele fica como a seguinte imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o meu HTML gerado para este form é o seguinte:

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="form-vertical edit_arquivo" id="edit_arquivo_1" action="/documentos/1/arquivos/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"></form>
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="HPAt+RG4IluAdpIhsNSdMw/tFQ2PF0CzIWUGhUwkZ+AXcyy0fZOLSW+EYMAkt1m56s+KMW25aEbce/MtfNjwwA==">
<tr>
   <td>
      <div class="form-group integer optional arquivo_score">
       <div class="controls">
         <div class="star-rating rating-xs rating-active">
           <div class="rating-container rating-gly-star" data-content="">
             <div class="rating-stars" data-content="" style="width: 80%;"></div>
               <input class="numeric integer optional rating form-control hide" type="number" step="1" name="arquivo[score]" id="arquivo_score"></div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Atualizar Arquivo" class="btn btn-default btn btn-default btn-primary btn-large"/>
   </td>
</tr>
```

**Mas, por algum motivo que eu nao faço ideia**, o parâmetro arquivo_score não é enviado para o meu controller, como o pacote mostra:

```
Started PATCH "/documentos/1/arquivos/1" for ::1 at 2015-02-20 17:18:53 -0300
Processing by ArquivosController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wB2bfSO4VgQyZ+No4zu5OY8hYgsO7WWI1GzSJ9E05LDLnpowT5P/Ft2VEYl3WH2zagP9N+xDTX0pcieP4chzkA==", "arquivo"=>{"cancelado"=>"0", "observacao"=>""}, "commit"=>"Atualizar Arquivo", "documento_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz do que está acontecendo? O que eu notei é que esse field possui um campo chamado `data-content`, que os outros não possuem, mas mesmo assim deveria estar sendo passado algum valor, não?

Comment: Cara, coloca o código rails completo, controller, view (_form) ;D

Comment: Não dá para saber muito por isso, mas você verificou se a biblioteca altera o valor (value) do campo? A única coisa que interessa para o rails é o value que vem do input.